# CodeIgniter URL repetition

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I just started CodeIgnitor, that's the first time I use MVC structure though, and I have a problem that I've never seen before... It's mainly in the "form" part, but also in the database display.
Also I use Xampp.
I've got a form to create an item to insert in the database, but whenever i click the submit button, things gets wrong in the url section.

My base URL is : *localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.1/* (CodeIgniter-3.1.1 is the directory that contain every php folder).

So the form page URL is : *localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.1/index.php/news/create*

And when i submit, it is : *localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.1/index.php/news/localhost/CodeIgniter-3.1.1/index.php/news/create*

It just repeat the entire URL after the controller (news).
I don't think it has to be with config.php, my base URL seems good, I just don't know.

Comment: Yes, we need some code. Likely, the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Make your base url `http://localhost/Codeigniter-3.1.1/index.php/` then in your `<form>` tag set the url like this `<form method="post" action="<?= base_url('news/create') ?>">`

Answer (score 1):

In `/application/config/config.php` set `$config['base_url']` like this

```
 $config['base_url'] = http://localhost/Codeigniter-3.1.1/
```

In your view do either one of the following to create the `<form>` tag

```
<form method="post" action="<?= base_url('news/create'); ?>">
```

of if you have loaded the "Form Helper" ([documented here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)) use this line in the view

```
<?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's handle by the framework, as so:

```html
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<?php echo form_open('news/create'); ?>

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="input" name="title" /><br />

    <label for="text">Text</label>
    <textarea name="text"></textarea><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create news item" />

</form>
```

Also, the problem occure when I  put a link to a view, like :

```html
<a href="<?php echo 'news/'.$news_item['slug']; ?>">
```

Instead of building the right URL it copy itself along the bar.

Comment: The URL repetition is because you don't have ` $config['base_url']` set correctly as all the answers have tried to tell you.

Comment: Yeah, i was writing this post when I got answer, i didn't see it then.... But it seems to work.
Thanks all :D